# Simple Camel run goal with blueprint gives exception

Tags: blueprint-osgi, blueprint

I have a simple maven project created based on camel blueprint archetype.
When I do "mvn camel:run" I see this error

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Gave up waiting for service (objectClass=org.apache.camel.CamelContext)
at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintHelper.getOsgiService(CamelBlueprintHelper.java:295)
at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintHelper.getOsgiService(CamelBlueprintHelper.java:256)
at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.Main.doStart(Main.java:110)
at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
at org.apache.camel.main.MainSupport.run(MainSupport.java:138)
at org.apache.camel.main.MainSupport.run(MainSupport.java:390)
at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.Main.main(Main.java:79)
```

Why is a test package being used ? I don't have anything in test scope or test classes. What is the sequence of the OsgiService creation and which class is supposed to create it ?

Comment: Which version? Can you share your pom?

Comment: My mistake. CamelContext was not getting created. I found that I had added a reference to a non existing bean. But it would have been helpful to see an exception indicating the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was CamelContext was not getting created. The problem went away when I removed the reference to an unknown class.

I move to karaf